# Comparison of Items displayed in different columns using C#/cshtml

Tags: c#, razor, arraylist, compare, comparison

I would like to make a comparison between the different columns in a table. The main focus of my comparison is to set

- text colour for similar text in different columns as grey
- text colour different text in different columns as black

This would in turn highlight the differences of my text in the different columns.

My < td> consist of several < p> generated by a foreach loop from my ArrayList.

```
if (@displayarray.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (string x in @displayarray)
        {
            <p>@x</p>
        }
    }
```

To display on my webpage i simply use the function above in my < td>

```
    <td>
         @DisplayOnTable(Array1)
    </td>
```

Here is a sample of how my table looks like currently,
[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eejr.png)

From the picture:

- Items in both columns are the same and text colour should be grey instead of black

Answer (score 0):

I think you could accomplish that with JQuery or even plain javascript

```
if ("#columnA" == "#columnB") { div.addClass("greyColor") }
```

or something like that